# When connecting using the mysql cli, why is there no space between -p and the password? e.g. -ppassword

Tags: mysql, mysql-cli

```
mysql -hhost -uuser -ppassword
```

Is there a rationale behind why there's no need for spaces? In fact, it wouldn't work unless there is no space.

Comment: Because that's the way they wrote it.

Answer (score 2):

Found my answer:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/command-line-options.html

It's just the way they wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a command like

```
mysql -h hostname -u username -p xxx
```

the command is ambiguous. It could mean that `xxx` is the password and no database was specified, or it could mean that `xxx` is the database and no password was specified (in which case `mysql` prompts for a password).

They chose the second interpretation. But if you use `-pxxx` then `xxx` can only be interpreted as the password.